# Is testing on OpenShift Container Platform (OCP) equivalent to testing on Openshift Origin from a kubernetes standpoint?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat

*This applications which are programmed to use the kubernetes API.*

Should we assume that openshift container platform, from a kubernetes standpoint, matches all the standards that openshift origin (and kubernetes) does?

*Background*

Compatibility testing cloud native apps that are shipped can include a large matrix.  It seems that, as a baseline, if OCP is meant to be a pure kubernetes distribution, with add ons, then testing against it is trivial, so long as you are only using core kubernetes features.

Alternatively, if shipping an app with support on OCP means you must test OCP, that would to me imply that (1) the app uses OCP functionality or (2) the app uses kube functionality which may not work correctly in OCP, which should be a considered a bug.

Answer (score 6):

In practice you should be able to regard OpenShift Container Platform (OCP) as being the same as OKD (previously known as Origin). This is because it is effectively the same software and setup.

In comparing both of these to plain Kubernetes there are a few things you need to keep in mind.

The OpenShift distribution of Kubernetes is set up as a multi-tenant system, with a clear distinction between normal users and administrators. This means RBAC is setup so that a normal user is restricted in what they can do out of the box. A normal user cannot for example create arbitrary resources which affect the whole cluster. They also cannot run images that will only work if run as `root` as they run under a default service account which doesn't have such rights. That default service also has no access to the REST API. A normal user has no privileges to enable the ability to run such images as `root`. A user who is a project admin, could allow an application to use the REST API, but what it could do via the REST API will be restricted to the project/namespace it runs in.

So if you develop an application on Kubernetes where you have an expectation that you have full admin access, and can create any resources you want, or assume there is no RBAC/SCC in place that will restrict what you can do, you can have issues getting it running.

This doesn't mean you can't get it working, it just means that you need to take extra steps so you or your application is granted extra privileges to do what it needs.

This is the main area where people have issues and it is because OpenShift is setup to be more secure out of the box to suit a multi-tenant environment for many users, or even to separate different applications so that they cannot interfere with each other.

The next thing worth mentioning is Ingress. When Kubernetes first came out, it had no concept of Ingress. To fill that hole, OpenShift implemented the concept of Routes. Ingress only came much later, and was based in part of what was done in OpenShift with Routes. That said, there are things you can do with Routes which I believe you still can't do with Ingress.

Anyway, obviously, if you use Routes, that only works on OpenShift as a plain Kubernetes cluster only has Ingress. If you use Ingress, you need to be using OpenShift 3.10 or later. In 3.10, there is an automatic mapping of Ingress to Route objects, so I believe Ingress should work even though OpenShift actually implements Ingress under the covers using Routes and its haproxy router setup.

There are obviously other differences as well. OpenShift has DeploymentConfig because Kubernetes never originally had Deployment. Again, there are things you can do with DeploymentConfig you can't do with Deployment, but Deployment object from Kubernetes is supported. One difference with DeploymentConfig is how it works in with ImageStream objects in OpenShift, which don't exist in Kubernetes. Stick with Deployment/StatefulSet/DaemonSet and don't use the OpenShift objects which were created when Kubernetes didn't have such features you should be fine.

Do note though that OpenShift takes a conservative approach on some resource types and so they may not by default be enabled. This is for things that are still regarded as alpha, or are otherwise in very early development and subject to change. You should avoid things which are still in development even if using plain Kubernetes.

That all said, for the core Kubernetes bits, OpenShift is verified for conformance against CNCF tests for Kubernetes. So use what is covered by that and you should be okay.

- https://www.cncf.io/certification/software-conformance/